# It has a meaning vs. it has meaning

Tags: meaning, articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

Sometimes I'm really confused with articles. I'd say 'everything has a meaning' but it seems that for some reason most people tend to say 'everything has meaning' instead. However, I've come across phrases like 'it has a meaning' as well. Hence, I'm not sure which one is more correct. Is it even correct to 'it has a meaning' in any context? And if both versions are correct, what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The definite article is there to define a specific meaning. In other words 'Everything has meaning' means that everything means something and 'Everything has a meaning' means that everything means something specific. It is just semantics, but the definite article only acts to create specificity.

Comment: Note that *a, an* is the **indefinite** (singular) article.